# Simple Docker Concept

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I'm going through the [getting started](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/) with Docker guide and understood most of the basics except for one concept.

[image: docker images screenshot]

I get how `docker/whalesay` takes up `247 MB`. It needs to download a few layers, including a base image of ubuntu. But `hello-world` should be around the same size? It's a self-contained image that can be shipped anywhere.

When `hello-world` executes, there's still a Linux layer running it somewhere, and I also downloaded `hello-world` before `docker/whalesay` so it couldn't have been using the Linux layer downloaded from `docker/whalesay`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

It is not an ubuntu instance. Check the hub: 
https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/

Here if you click on latest, you can see the dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
COPY hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

The FROM defines which operating system it is based on. Scratch is an "empty" image, as described here: https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/

Comment: So it is copying the hello program to my current working directory on my host machine?

Comment: It will never create a directory on working directory as I understand it, it's still a seperate image with its own environment, it's just really minimal. So it will be stored the same way all docker images are stored. For example, it won't have a package manager on it. But you can use it as a base to create a larger image to ensure you have nothing on it you don't need. Things like this image as well as busybox are often used to for weaker hardware in things like a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/blob/85fd7ab65e079b08019032479a3f306964a28f4d/hello-world/Dockerfile) clears things up - it's not using any base image i.e Ubuntu, etc:

```
FROM scratch
COPY hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

The first directive `FROM` states the base image for the new image we intend to build. From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/from):

> The `FROM` instruction sets the Base Image for subsequent instructions.
>   As such, a valid `Dockerfile` must have `FROM` as its first instruction.
>   The image can be any valid image – it is especially easy to start by
>   pulling an image from the Public Repositories. (Docker Hub)

And `FROM scratch` (no way it is using any base image, hence the mini image size) is a special case - the term `scratch` is reserved - from the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/):

> **`FROM scratch`**
>
> This image is most useful in the context of building base images (such
>   as debian and busybox) or super minimal images (that contain only a
>   single binary and whatever it requires, such as hello-world).

also

> As of Docker 1.5.0 (specifically, docker/docker#8827), FROM scratch is
>   a no-op in the Dockerfile, and will not create an extra layer in your
>   image (so a previously 2-layer image will be a **1-layer image instead**).

---

**EDIT 1** - OP's new comment to clarify it further:

> To clarify, there's a very minimal Linux dist installed with Docker.
>   And this incredibly simple hello-world image uses that default Linux
>   dist that comes with Docker?

A good clarification by Paul Becotte:

> No. Docker does not contain a kernel- it is not a virtual machine. It
>   is a way to run processes on your existing kernel in such a way as to
>   trick them into thinking they are completely isolated. The size of the
>   image is actually a "root file system" ... in this case, the file
>   system contains only a single file, which is why it is small. **The
>   process actually gets executed on the kernel that is running the
>   Docker Daemon** (you Linux machine on which you installed Docker), with it chroot'ed to the container filesystem.

---

To clarify it further - I am sharing an example of using a minimal image [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/):

> A minimal Docker image based on Alpine Linux with a complete package
>   index and only 5 MB in size!

---

**P.S.** In case of `hello-world` there isn't any base image not even a minimlistic one.

Comment: To clarify, there's a very minimal Linux dist installed with Docker. And this incredibly simple `hello-world` image uses that default Linux dist that comes with Docker?

Comment: No. Docker does not contain a kernel- it is not a virtual machine. It is a way to run processes on your existing kernel in such a way as to trick them into thinking they are completely isolated. The size of the image is actually a "root file system" ... in this case, the file system contains only a single file, which is why it is small. The process actually gets executed on the kernel that is running the Docker Daemon, with it chroot'ed to the container filesystem.

Comment: @PaulBecotte and @Nabeel Thank you for all the clarification. I'm very close to understanding. When you say it runs on the kernel that is running the Docker Daemon, does that mean the `hello-world`binary is running from my Mac OS X Yosemite kernel since I'm using Docker for Mac? The clarification would make sense if I was using Docker on Linux but since I'm on Mac I figured it'd be running on a small Linux kernel that comes with Docker, or now after your explanation, off the Mac UNIX kernel.

Comment: No, I am sorry.  Docker for Mac includes an actual linux virtual machine which runs a docker daemon and proxies your docker commands to that machine.  So there IS a linux installation with the Docker for Mac - but that has nothing to do with any of your images.

Comment: @PaulBecotte but when it comes to the [`hello-world`](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/tree/85fd7ab65e079b08019032479a3f306964a28f4d/hello-world) image, it is running off of that linux virtual machine when I use Docker for Mac correct?

Comment: Yes, the kernel that it runs on is the kernal in the virtual machine that docker for mac installed on your machine.  The image itself doesn't contain a kernel, just a root filesystem.